# Suppressing @unchecked warning for a higher-kinded existential type

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, higher-kinded-types

In Scala 2.10, given `class Foo[F[_]]`, I can't write

```
scala> x.isInstanceOf[Foo[_]]
<console>:10: error: _$1 takes no type parameters, expected: one
              x.isInstanceOf[Foo[_]]
                                 ^
```

or

```
scala> x.isInstanceOf[Foo[_[_]]]
<console>:11: error: _$1 does not take type parameters
              x.isInstanceOf[Foo[_[_]]]
                                 ^
```

I *can* write `x.isInstanceOf[Foo[F] forSome { type F[_]] }`, which gives an unchecked warning. I've tried placing `@unchecked` annotation in different places, but none of them work:

```
scala> x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H] @unchecked forSome {type H[_]}]
<console>:11: warning: abstract type H in type Foo[H] @unchecked forSome { type H[_] <: Any } is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H] @unchecked forSome {type H[_]}]
                            ^

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H @unchecked] forSome {type H[_]}]
<console>:11: warning: abstract type H in type Foo[H @unchecked] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
              x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H @unchecked] forSome {type H[_]}]
                            ^
<console>:11: error: kinds of the type arguments (? @unchecked) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F) in class Foo.
? @unchecked's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
<none> has no type parameters, but type F has one
              x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H @unchecked] forSome {type H[_]}]
                                               ^

scala> x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H] forSome {type H[_] @unchecked}]
<console>:1: error: `=', `>:', or `<:' expected
       x.isInstanceOf[Foo[H] forSome {type H[_] @unchecked}]
                                                ^
```

Is there any way to write this existential type without a warning?

Comment: I think `@unchecked` is only for pattern matching (on the object for exhaustiveness (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.unchecked)). You can give a try with pattern matching though, like `obj match _: Foo[_] => ???`.

Comment: @GáborBakos It's surprising that `Foo[_]` works in this context, but not in `isInstanceOf`. If I remember correctly, I did try pattern matching earlier, but only using `forSome`, and none of the variations I've tried worked.

Comment: @GáborBakos Please make this a reply, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pattern matching you can keep the warnings away:

```
x match {case _: Foo[_] => ???}
```

It is also a bit less verbose in my opinion. In case you name the `case` variable (starting with lower case letter or escaped with back quotes, ie. not `_` as in the above example before `:`), you already have an `asInstanceOf`.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of guessing:

```
$ scala210 -language:_
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo[F[_]]
defined class Foo

scala> (null: Any).isInstanceOf[(Foo[F] forSome { type F[_] }) @unchecked]
res0: Boolean = false
```

The pop-up just told me code blocks are not very informative.

Oh, and `s/guessing/experimenting`.

Comment: For me it works in Scala 2.10, but doesn't in 2.11.5 (I'm getting the usual warning).