# Scala higher-kinded existential type

Tags: scala

I have the following hierarchy and I would like to define a list of any `Description` but can't figure out its parameter type.

```
abstract class Context
class Local extends Context
class Browsing extends Context

abstract class Fruit[C <: Context]
class Apple[C <: Context](id: Int) extends Fruit[C]
class Banana[C <: Context](id: Int) extends Fruit[C]

abstract class Description[U[X <: Context] <: Fruit[X]] // U can't be covariant
class Apples extends Description[Apple]
class Bananas extends Description[Banana]
```

Basically, I would like something like this (which doesn't compile as is):

```
val l: List[Description[_]] = List(
    new Apples,
    new Bananas
)
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: How you expect to use that `l`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182694/how-to-define-an-existential-higher-kinded-type-in-scala or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176807/suppressing-unchecked-warning-for-a-higher-kinded-existential-type

Comment: Actually, I could use a superclass for `Description` without parameter type and use the methods on those. But inside `Description`, I have reference to other objects parameterized with `U` and would be therefore forced to create superclass for those as well (and their children… it's a whole hierarchy). The only point is to keep as much information about the type as I can without creating any additional abstract layers.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is this:

```
abstract class Description[+U[X <: Context] <: Fruit[X]]
```

And then it will work:

```
scala> List(new Apples, new Bananas)
res40: List[Description[Fruit]] = List(Apples@6a808ae5, Bananas@4f4d77e8)
```

The reason on why your case fails is: When you do `List(new Apples, new Bananas)`, because the compiler tries finding the least upper bound (LUB) for `Apples` and `Banana`. i.e. LUB for `Description[Apple]` and `Description[Banana]`. So what you need is `Description[_ >: Banana with Apple <: Fruit]`.

As the compiler error rightly says: `Apple <: Fruit` (and of-course Apple >: Banana with Apple). But `Description[Apple]` will only be a subtype of `Description[_ >: Banana with Apple <: Fruit]` if `Description` is co-variant in its type parameter.

PS: Co-variance gives us the ability to have this:
If `A <: B` and then for `M[+T]`, `M[A] <: M[B]`.

For contra-variance `M[-T]`, `M[A] >: M[B]`