# WeakTypeTag for higher kinded type

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming, scala-macros, higher-kinded-types

Consider the following macro declaration:

```
def someMacro[Alg[_[_]]](c: Context)(implicit alg: c.WeakTypeTag[Alg[_]])
```

Unfortunately it does not compile. The error:

```
 _$2 takes no type parameters, expected: 1
```

Is there a way to fix it up?

Comment: What is this `Alg[_[_]]` supposed to be... is this a typo ?

Comment: @sarveshseri Just a higher kinded type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `WeakTypeTag` for a higher-kinded existential type (in `forSome` notation)

```
def someMacro[Alg[_[_]]](c: Context)(implicit alg: c.WeakTypeTag[Alg[F]] forSome { type F[_] })
```

[Self-type annotation for class with higher kinded type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61215541/self-type-annotation-for-class-with-higher-kinded-type)

[Searching for implicit inside a reify call (scala macro)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807221/searching-for-implicit-inside-a-reify-call-scala-macro)

[Is there a shorthand for type variable 'm forSome { type m[O] <: UpperBound[O] }` in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041172/is-there-a-shorthand-for-type-variable-m-forsome-type-mo-upperboundo)

[How to define an existential higher kinded type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182694/how-to-define-an-existential-higher-kinded-type-in-scala)

[Existential Higher Kinded Method Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738447/existential-higher-kinded-method-parameter)